# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Only when running MUnit test

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, munit

I am attempting the run an MUnit test and everytime I try to run it I receive this error in the console:

Unrecognized option: -esb
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have tried to access the ini file and both decrease and increase the heap size, I have rebooted my pc, and i have stripped the project of it's metadata and then re-imported the project.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I made this its own question instead of merging it with another question on here because this only happens when I try to run an MUnit test. It does not happen when trying to load Anypoint Studio or when I run any of my flows within the project. Just when I try to run this one MUnit suite.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug on the MUnit Studio Plugin. It'll be fixed in the next release(due in a couple of weeks)

I reckon you're running your test from studio, correct?
For the time being, as a workaround, please remove any "-" from your project name. In fact from anywhere in project path.

HTH

Comment: I appreciate the quick response but I am unable to remove the "-" from my files in this path. I have a specific naming pattern that I have to follow. But i guess I will just have to wait for the next release then.

Comment: If you are not using native libraries in your application you can also remove this property from your run configuration:

-Djava.library.path

Comment: I tried that and it blew up with like twelve errors about not being able to set beans.